# Double tunnel with Putty

Tags: linux, windows, putty, ssh-tunnel

I need to give LinuxHost1 access to HttpHost3:

```
LinuxHost1 --> MyWidnowsPC --> LinuxHost2 --> HttpHost3
```

- LinuxHost1 and LinuxHost2 cannot see to each other.
- MyWidnowsPC can see HttpHost3 but is under firewall.

I'm trying to create two tunnels with Putty in MyWidnowsPC:

Tunnel 1) **MyWidnowsPC**'s Putty client on **LinuxHost1**

```
L 7080 LinuxHost2:7080
```

Tunnel 2) **MyWidnowsPC**'s Putty client on **LinuxHost2**

```
L 7080 HttpHost3:80
```

But it seems not to be working [**MyWidnowsPC**'s Putty terminal on **LinuxHost1**]:

```
wget http://localhost:7080/
```

Is NOT getting any web content from **HttpHost3**.

I've tried with port 22 for LinuxHost2 (Tunnel 1) with no success, neither.

Anything am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

**Tunnel 1)** MyWidnowsPC's Putty client on LinuxHost1 must be Remote and point to MyWindowsPC (localhost):

> **R** 7180 localhost:80

**Tunnel 2)** MyWidnowsPC's Putty client on LinuxHost2 was fine, but it was unnecessary to change the HTTP port:

> **L** 80 HttpHost3:80

Now I received the index.html file with wget from LinuxHost1:

```
wget http://localhost:7180/
```

$ Saving to: `index.html'